# How to modify the default animation of Angular Material MatDialog?

Tags: angular-material2

By default, the dialog appears coming from bottom to top with some speed.

modify the delay to 3 seconds by using animation property of component metadata.

here is code link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1yfpy

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and [edit] your question in order to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way that you can modify the animation of the dialog as the animations of the dialog are done programmatically with Angular Animations.

As for the reason why the dialogs are displaying below each other, that's because you didn't include a theme in your app!

Modify the `styles.css` file to the following code:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```